# java web кодировка

Tags: java, веб-программирование, кодировка, tomcat

Создал веб приложение на сервлетах с сервером tomcat и столкнулся с проблемой кодировки.

Французские символы выводятся в консоль и записываются в файл в таком виде

> Rue AndrГ© CitroГ«n

Переменную JAVA_OPTS я определил в файле setenv.bat как

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dfile.encoding=UTF8"
```

Charset.defaultCharset() у меня выводит "UTF-8" 
При этом в БД MySQL у меня записывает всё отлично без крякозябры.

Comment: У вас очевидно проблема с кодировкой консоли, то есть в какой кодировке работает сама консоль

Comment: у вас ОС Windows?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman да, Windows 7

Comment: Проблема в кодировке самого файла с расширением .csv, в .txt всё выводится нормально

Comment: консоль в windows использует другую кодировку и не все символы в ней доступны.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman забыл добавить, что запускаю через ide idea